# "How can I display a html email in an asp.net-core webpage"

Tags: asp.net-core

Hi guy's I have been slamming google for a week on this one "How can I display an html emails in an asp.net-core webpage" the main problem being is the email styling takes over the whole page. Is there a way I can constrain it to the box its in?

```
<div>
  @Html.Raw(Model.Email.Body)
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you put it into a page on it's own (with a vanilla `_Layout` or no layout if your email has html and body tags) then inject it into your containing page (the one that's being corrupted currently) with an `iFrame`? Seems it could be the quickest way around the issue.